# What is the code behind for datagridtemplatecolumn, and how to use it?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a `DataGrid` in WPF. And I am trying to add `Button`s to certain cells of the grid, after it is bound to a particular `ItemsSource`. I have tried to do this in the xaml like this:

```
<dg:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="R1" CanUserReorder="False" IsReadOnly="False">             
    <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <awc:ImageButton Content="Edit" Name="btnEdit" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

However, I want to know as to how I can do this in the code behind. I need this so that I can place `Button`s whenever a particular click even takes place. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

use this:

```
DataGridTemplateColumn col1 = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
col1.Header = "MyHeader";
FrameworkElementFactory factory1 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
Binding b1 = new Binding("IsSelected");
b1.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
factory1.SetValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, b1);
factory1.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(chkSelect_Checked));
DataTemplate cellTemplate1 = new DataTemplate();
cellTemplate1.VisualTree = factory1;
col1.CellTemplate = cellTemplate1;
dgTransportReqsts.DataGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
```

I used this to add CheckBox in my DataGridTemplateColumn at runtime.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sorry for bumping an old thread, but in case of Button at `FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button))` , how do I add the Button Text? I have been unable to do so, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Manish Sinha, use factory1.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, b1); You can set any property of Button in your case in the same way I am setting the IsChecked property of CheckBox in above example.

Answer (score 3):

Anurag's answer will work very well for you if you want to add the buttons **before the grid is instantiated**, specifically before you add the column to the grid.

If you want to add the button to the grid cell **after the grid is already built**, you can do it by making changes to the DataGridCell object.  First you have to find it:

1. Find the `DataGridCell` by using `DataGridColumn.GetCellContent`
2. Use `VisualTreeHelper` to scan up the visual tree to the `DataGridCell`

Once this is done, there are several ways to add a button to the DataGridCell, depending on what you're trying to achieve:

- Set `DataGridCell.Template` to a ControlTemplate containing the buttons and other styling you desire, -OR-
- Set `DataGridCell.ContentTemplate` to a DataTemplate containing the buttons and other items you desire, -OR-
- Have your column's `DataTemplate` include a placeholder panel to hold new buttons, search down the visual tree for this panel by `Name`, and add your button to it.

An alternative approach that doesn't require finding the cell is to:

1. Include an `ObservableCollection<T>` property in your view model that supplies the information to create the buttons
2. In your `DataTemplate` include an `ItemsControl` that reference this property and has a `DataTemplate` that can create the correct button out of type `T`
3. When you want to add a button, just add an item to the `ObservableCollection` property