# How to bind a datagrid to a class in which one member is a list?

Tags: c#, list, data-binding, datagrid

I've seen some similar posts about that.
Here the difference is that I don't want to have to manually set all columns binding.

So I have a class

```
 public class PartProgram
{
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public string Note { get; set; }    
  public string PartProgramFilename { get; set; }
  public List<String> LstBlades { get; set; }
}
```

and I have binded it to a datagridView through:

```
 dtgPPtab3.ItemsSource = olstPartPrograms;
```

where

```
 public ObservableCollection<PartProgram> olstPartPrograms = new ObservableCollection<PartProgram>();
```

this works fine nearly everywhere and the result is the one in the pic below:

[image]

So all the columns are correct but the last one in which I would like to have the collection value changed to something like blade1, blade2, etc.

Comment: @Soner Gönül just to understand. Is the edit for it's wrong to put  the programming language in the title of for here it's a general question not related to C# WPF?

Comment: Question can be related C# and WPF but putting tags in a title is usually unnecessary. You can read [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/158761)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so thanks everyone for helping but I've found a very easy solution taken from http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/

Imagine having a class binded to a datagrid:

```
 ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
 List<String> lst = new List<string>();
 lst.Add("AAA");
 lst.Add("BBB");
 lst.Add("CCC");
 users.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", Str = lst });
 dg.ItemsSource = users;
```

if I want the details in the class I add the accessor details:

```
 public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<String> Str { get; set; }
    public string Details<--------------------------------
    {
        get
        {
            String locStr=string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in this.Str)
                locStr += item + ", ";
            return locStr;
        }
    }
}
```

which provides the magic for having an understandable version of the list. 
So the result is:
[image: i get a string from a list]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an ItemsControl (DataGrid/ListView etc) to show collection column contents.

Eg;

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LstBlades }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: i get an exception  Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

Comment: would you please elaborate my peculiar case in code behind?

Comment: It's similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754608/what-is-the-code-behind-for-datagridtemplatecolumn-and-how-to-use-it but I can't fit it to work in my case that is to work only on column3 and how to format the list like str1, str2,...

Comment: @Patrick For further formatting, you can use DataGridTemplateColumn in inner datagrid.