# Displaying 3-dimensional data in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am trying to display a 3-dimensional data in a WPF `DataGrid` via `DataTable` binding. Since `DataGrid` only has rows and columns (2D), my idea is to template cells so that they host a `ListView` (or some other control), and display the third dimension values stacked vertically.

The desired result is this:

[image]

Here is a heavily simplified but reproducible code with mock data, my attempt at for creating such a `DataTable`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel vm = new();

        MyDataGrid.DataContext = vm.Table.DefaultView;
        MyDataGrid.IsReadOnly = true;
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public DataTable Table { get; init; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Table = new DataTable();

            Table.Columns.Add(" ");
            Table.Columns.Add("c1");
            Table.Columns.Add("c2");
            Table.Columns.Add("c3");

            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ )
            {
                DataRow row = Table.NewRow();

                row[0] = new List<object>() { "r" + i } ;
                row[1] = new List<object>() { 10 * i, 20 * i, 25 * i } ;
                row[2] = new List<object>() { 12 * i, 26 * i, 30 * i } ;
                row[3] = new List<object>() { 16 * i, 28 * i, 36 * i };

                Table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am assigning List to each cell, idea being that this creates the third dimension, storing multiple values in a single cell.

Problem is, I don't know how to template the DataGrid in the WPF markup so that this third dimension is correctly unpacked and displayed like in that image I've shown above. I tried this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridTemplate">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DataGridTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

But when I compile and run it, `DataGrid` just shows empty cells, even though there are no binding errors. If I don't use any template, cells show `System.Data.DataRowView System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]`.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could take a look (the code I provided above is fully reproducible example), and let me know how to create the correct template? Or, if I'm going about this the wrong way, I'm open to other suggestions as well.

EDIT: clarification: in my full application, the number of columns and rows, and their header names is not known in advance, and might change during runtime, so the `DataGrid` must be bound in a way that allows these changes to be reflected when the underlying `DataTable` is modified or recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code as you have it.

#### 1 - Add the `Type` for the complex `DataTable` columns

Issue 1 is that your columns are not typed, and this seems to be resulting in `DataRow["c1"]` etc showing as a `string` value of the type `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Int32]` rather than the collection itself. See the debugger screenshot below:
[image]

You will need to update those columns and add the types as shown below (note that I also named the first column so that we can reference it).

```cs
// row headers
Table.Columns.Add("c0", typeof(string)); 
// three-dimensional data
Table.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(IList));
Table.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(IList));
Table.Columns.Add("c3", typeof(IList));
```

#### 2 - Use `DataGridTemplateColumn` to build the complex `DataGrid` columns

The second challenge is that I don't think that you can accomplish what you want with auto-generated columns. If I change your `CellTemplate` to just bind to a `TextBlock`, you can see that the data context for those cells is actually the whole `DataRowView` object and not just the bound column:

```xml
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

[image]

Updating your `DataGrid` as shown below, I was able to generate what I believe you are looking for.

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding c0}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="c1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding c1}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="c2">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding c2}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="c3">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding c3}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

#### Result

[image]

#### UPDATE: 3 - If auto-generating columns is required...

If your use case requires you to auto-generate columns, as mentioned in the comment, you can override the column generation for those specific columns. This approach is a little less clean and relies on building those columns in the code-behind. The example below references these two links:

[How to: Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755556/15534202)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1755556/15534202

**XAML:** Add an auto-generation event handler

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            AutoGeneratingColumn="MyDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn">
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind:** Override generation of `List` columns

```cs
private void MyDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // Optional: Remove the column header for the row headers
    if (e.Column.Header == "c0") e.Column.Header = "";

    // Let the non-list data auto-generate normally
    if (!e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList))) return;

    // create a new column
    var newColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    newColumn.Header = e.Column.Header;
            
    // create a new binding
    var binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName);
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

    // setup the cell template
    var elementFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ListBox));
    elementFactory.SetValue(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
    var newCellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
    newCellTemplate.VisualTree = elementFactory;
    newColumn.CellTemplate = newCellTemplate;
            
    // assign the new column
    e.Column = newColumn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is very detailed and informative. The issue is that I do not know how many columns and rows will there be, nor what their header names will be. Therefore they cannot be explicitly defined in WPF markup, they need to be generated from the DataTable. Sorry if I didn't make this clear in my post. Could you please update your answer to account for this? I will edit my post and clarify this for other people.

Comment: Gotcha. I think I have an idea. I'll post an update shortly.

Comment: @JR, I added an option for auto-generating columns. It doesn't use XAML to build the template and instead uses the code-behind, but I don't know if there is a way around that. Let me know if this works for your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much, this third option seems like what I need. I just can't quite figure out, why is showing empty first column (where the row headers should be, "r1", "r2" and "r3"?

Comment: Did you make sure to include the check for the column type? ` if (!e.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IList))) return;`

Comment: I am pretty sure that the header row column showed up correctly in my prototype, but that is on another computer.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. This is my C# code: [link](https://pastebin.com/H4JGPisp), and here is the WPF markup: [link](https://pastebin.com/Dqgj0C3j)

Comment: The first column should not have the IList type: 
                Table.Columns.Add(" ", typeof(IList));

Comment: Table.Columns.Add(" ") // first column only

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but then the first column just shows "System.Data.DataRowView" in every cell.

Comment: Interestingly though, if I write `Table.Columns.Add("c0", typeof(IList))` instead of `Table.Columns.Add("", typeof(IList))`, the it does start working. Not sure why, I'd rather have that first column header blank.

Comment: That is odd... I guess there is something with how the autogenerate columns is working if you don't supply a name. This is working as I think you want it  https://pastebin.com/UvmpVVWE

Comment: If that works for you, I will update my answer

Comment: It does seem a bit like a hack, but yes, it works. Feel free to update the answer, I will mark it as correct. I'm just now wondering if perhaps choosing DataGrid was the wrong turn if it requires such manual column creation, and doesn't seem to provide any diagnostic tools to understand why is it not working when something goes wrong. Maybe I should have gone with ListView/GridView instead? In any case, thank you very much for your answer, it is extremely high quality. I would upvote twice if I could.

Comment: @JR, I updated the answer, so go ahead and accept it if it worked for you. I'm glad it helped!